# Muscle involved in carrying load on head

Tags: human-anatomy, muscles, bio-mechanics

I have seen people carrying heavy load on their head especially in 3rd world countries, does carrying on head any benefit or harm, which muscle get strengthen in doing it?

Comment: Not really an answer, but an interesting related article: http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/explainer/2010/08/head_case.html